# After updating none of my custom fields show

Tags: error-message, craft-pro, updates

I updated to craft 2.6.2780 and now I cant see any fields on entries after checking inspector it seems that php is this throwing an error.

Here is the stack trace

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /Users/jerome/Projects/aiglon/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node.php on line 145
Call Stack
# Time  Memory  Function  Location
1 0.0009  241864  {main}( ) ../index.php:0
2 0.0033  440584  require_once( '/Users/jerome/Projects/aiglon/craft/app/index.php' ) ../index.php:31
3 0.1099  10459104  CApplication->run( )  ../index.php:62
4 0.1099  10461112  Craft\WebApp->processRequest( ) ../CApplication.php:185
5 0.1999  15650696  CWebApplication->processRequest( )  ../WebApp.php:288
6 0.2025  15938760  CWebApplication->runController( ) ../CWebApplication.php:141
7 0.2083  16649144  CController->run( ) ../CWebApplication.php:282
8 0.2090  16694152  CController->runActionWithFilters( )  ../CController.php:265
9 0.2090  16694296  CController->runAction( ) ../CController.php:286
10  0.2091  16695696  CInlineAction->runWithParams( ) ../CController.php:308
11  0.2091  16696272  CAction->runWithParamsInternal( ) ../CInlineAction.php:47
12  0.2091  16697296  invokeArgs ( )  ../CAction.php:109
13  0.2092  16699544  Craft\EntriesController->actionEditEntry( ) ../CAction.php:109
14  0.4346  23739520  Craft\BaseController->renderTemplate( ) ../EntriesController.php:338
15  0.4346  23739712  Craft\TemplatesService->render( ) ../BaseController.php:74
16  0.4446  24822064  Twig_Environment->render( ) ../TemplatesService.php:246
17  0.4560  25991112  Twig_Template->render( )  ../Environment.php:347
18  0.4560  26008360  Twig_Template->display( ) ../Template.php:366
19  1.5365  26493504  Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling( ) ../Template.php:355
20  1.5365  26493712  Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling( )  ../BaseTemplate.php:26
21  1.5365  26494408  __TwigTemplate_f8cf647abe35f0f0e2b74a673c12e9c153bbdae0fe4f9a52317d6f0cbef29919->doDisplay( ) ../Template.php:381
22  1.5409  26909808  Twig_Template->display( ) ../1ab3b758ddc29102de0a2a3426a0b984479ce84a67bce3468f2bfdd985918a54.php:53
23  1.5409  26910736  Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling( ) ../Template.php:355
24  1.5409  26910736  Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling( )  ../BaseTemplate.php:26
25  1.5409  26911488  __TwigTemplate_e77ed92aa7988e9c51328e050cece8cacc2a4d0bb697e6268fabe71996e537ab->doDisplay( ) ../Template.php:381
26  1.6778  27401304  Twig_Template->display( ) ../c4729b5ea7be1022d5c997c520461e3e556ed6fa730be71edd4226a06597d3dc.php:165
27  1.6779  27402352  Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling( ) ../Template.php:355
28  1.6779  27402352  Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling( )  ../BaseTemplate.php:26
29  1.6779  27403816  __TwigTemplate_f4c044be1ad93a456f5b792a5ea6839002cbb5321ca4fed8631bc413b4f560db->doDisplay( ) ../Template.php:381
30  1.6911  27748184  Twig_Template->display( ) ../99c63674c7847eb768f7396b0a8d85a5c4045d44723c606bcbe70506672c4f92.php:131
31  1.6912  27749304  Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling( ) ../Template.php:355
32  1.6912  27749304  Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling( )  ../BaseTemplate.php:26
33  1.6912  27749632  __TwigTemplate_a7a80a11c0ed984b9a02484ab4491fe185e9a5d4877c3fa3a6c3833c30d665ce->doDisplay( ) ../Template.php:381
34  1.6984  28420648  Twig_Template->displayBlock( )  ../ceafcd2cd2e3ab1ee29def2ae7ee4d848e03e99baf7863170b3e329031ed8257.php:45
35  1.6984  28424960  __TwigTemplate_e77ed92aa7988e9c51328e050cece8cacc2a4d0bb697e6268fabe71996e537ab->block_body( )  ../Template.php:167
36  2.6415  30805960  Twig_Template->renderBlock( ) ../c4729b5ea7be1022d5c997c520461e3e556ed6fa730be71edd4226a06597d3dc.php:655
37  2.6415  30822584  Twig_Template->displayBlock( )  ../Template.php:229
38  2.6415  30825904  __TwigTemplate_f8cf647abe35f0f0e2b74a673c12e9c153bbdae0fe4f9a52317d6f0cbef29919->block_main( )  ../Template.php:167
39  2.6439  30914272  Twig_Template->display( ) ../1ab3b758ddc29102de0a2a3426a0b984479ce84a67bce3468f2bfdd985918a54.php:378
40  2.6439  30914664  Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling( ) ../Template.php:355
41  2.6439  31045648  Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling( )  ../BaseTemplate.php:26
42  2.6439  31045968  __TwigTemplate_291c4b321d5fd418706b404a0856597dabcd40ad90cdceeabd7dcaf7bbadc9a9->doDisplay( ) ../Template.php:381
43  2.7723  31670296  Twig_Template->display( ) ../e56e3889fb9fcfc3e18bc98f6987bb0e3dab3d2ae543efebdcdff1f7c60f7905.php:58
44  2.7724  31672808  Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling( ) ../Template.php:355
45  2.7724  31672808  Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling( )  ../BaseTemplate.php:26
46  2.7724  31673360  __TwigTemplate_81f12d81663a85d99f185a10360565a47affbdcfb8d25e4db9e17a56bc2a120e->doDisplay( ) ../Template.php:381
47  2.7741  31783112  Twig_Template->display( ) ../3e1afd1389dbaf0c5f9367ffc7ca788bb5ccd01be8f9e50b79fd988052989e30.php:47
48  2.7741  31785712  Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling( ) ../Template.php:355
49  2.7741  31785712  Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling( )  ../BaseTemplate.php:26
50  2.7741  31786760  __TwigTemplate_194eb62d3f869941f884bc57bdefcbe5a1b61c0991eef48bb97e1f27d5ecfb15->doDisplay( ) ../Template.php:381
51  2.7770  31914192  Craft\BaseTemplate->getAttribute( ) ../a5ef763b9421b08aeee887a78999a3a5322aa1c8ba4a2eab68801778ff7038b3.php:52
52  2.7770  31914288  Twig_Template->getAttribute( )  ../BaseTemplate.php:64
53  2.7770  31915072  call_user_func_array:{/Users/jerome/Projects/aiglon/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:609} ( ) ../Template.php:609
54  2.7770  31915976  Craft\MatrixFieldType->getInputHtml( )  ../Template.php:609
55  2.7837  32255128  Craft\TemplatesService->render( ) ../MatrixFieldType.php:281
56  2.7837  32255128  Twig_Environment->render( ) ../TemplatesService.php:246
57  2.7837  32255128  Craft\TwigEnvironment->loadTemplate( )  ../Environment.php:347
58  2.7837  32255176  Twig_Environment->loadTemplate( ) ../TwigEnvironment.php:23
59  2.7846  32259496  Twig_Environment->compileSource( )  ../Environment.php:396
60  2.8584  35194320  Twig_Environment->compile( )  ../Environment.php:667
61  2.8592  35243968  Twig_Compiler->compile( ) ../Environment.php:651
62  2.8592  35244408  Twig_Node_Module->compile( )  ../Compiler.php:86
63  2.8592  35244768  Twig_Node_Module->compileTemplate( )  ../Module.php:52
64  2.8595  35247784  Twig_Node_Module->compileDisplay( ) ../Module.php:80
65  2.8595  35247864  Twig_Compiler->subcompile( )  ../Module.php:277
66  2.8595  35247960  Twig_Node->compile( ) ../Compiler.php:97
67  2.8595  35247960  Twig_Node->compile( ) ../Node.php:110
68  2.8603  35255936  Twig_Node_For->compile( ) ../Node.php:110
69  2.8605  35256792  Twig_Compiler->subcompile( )  ../For.php:83
70  2.8605  35256840  Twig_Node->compile( ) ../Compiler.php:97
71  2.8605  35256840  Twig_Node->compile( ) ../Node.php:110
72  2.8620  35261872  Twig_Node_If->compile( )  ../Node.php:110
73  2.8623  35262184  Twig_Compiler->subcompile( )  ../If.php:44
74  2.8623  35262232  Twig_Node->compile( ) ../Compiler.php:97
75  2.8674  35285912  Twig_Node_For->compile( ) ../Node.php:110
76  2.8676  35286224  Twig_Compiler->subcompile( )  ../For.php:83
77  2.8676  35286272  Twig_Node->compile( ) ../Compiler.php:97
78  2.8676  35286272  Twig_Node->compile( ) ../Node.php:110
79  2.8679  35287600  Twig_Node_Print->compile( ) ../Node.php:110
80  2.8680  35287624  Twig_Compiler->subcompile( )  ../Print.php:30
81  2.8680  35287672  Twig_Node_Expression_Filter->compile( ) ../Compiler.php:97
82  2.8680  35288600  Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileCallable( ) ../Filter.php:37
83  2.8680  35288664  Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileArguments( )  ../Call.php:30
84  2.8680  35288728  Twig_Compiler->subcompile( )  ../Call.php:70
85  2.8680  35288776  Twig_Node_Expression_Filter->compile( ) ../Compiler.php:97
86  2.8681  35289600  Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileCallable( ) ../Filter.php:37
87  2.8681  35289656  Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileArguments( )  ../Call.php:30
88  2.8682  35290032  Twig_Compiler->subcompile( )  ../Call.php:83
89  2.8682  35290080  Twig_Node_Expression_Array->compile( )  ../Compiler.php:97
90  2.8683  35290840  Twig_Compiler->subcompile( )  ../Array.php:76
91  2.8683  35290888  Twig_Node_Expression_Filter->compile( ) ../Compiler.php:97
92  2.8683  35291712  Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileCallable( ) ../Filter.php:37
93  2.8683  35291776  Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileArguments( )  ../Call.php:30
94  2.8684  35291824  Twig_Compiler->subcompile( )  ../Call.php:70
95  2.8684  35291872  Twig_Node_Expression_GetAttr->compile( )  ../Compiler.php:97
96  2.8684  35291896  Twig_Compiler->subcompile( )  ../GetAttr.php:31
97  2.8684  35291944  Twig_Node_Expression_Name->compile( ) ../Compiler.php:97
98  2.8684  35291944  Twig_Node_Expression_Name->isSpecial( ) ../Name.php:37
99  2.8684  35291992  Twig_Node->getAttribute( )  ../Name.php:83
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `xdebug`, then it looks like it might be solved by this previous StackOverflow answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4293870/1809628

In a nutshell, your `php.ini` will have a setting:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level
```

By default this is set to 100, so you just need to increase it.

Comment: No worries, I had same issue a while back.